# Use method argument as placeholder for chained relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

```
class Category
  has_many :posts
  has_many :images
end
```

Is it possible to chain a relation like below without explicitly write the plural form of the associated model? And if possible, of what type should the argument be?

```
def get_all(children_of_certain_model)
  self.children_of_certain_model.size
end
# one_category.get_all(:posts)
```

I know that for the case above I could simple call `one_category.posts` directly, but I'm just curious in general if it at all is possible to abstract the chained relation.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. Or even what the question is.

Comment: Updated the question with a bit more information, sorry if it's a super stupid question.

Comment: I think you're looking for `public_send`: `self.public_send(:posts).size`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sergio Tulentsev suggested, you can use `public_send` to call only public methods with symbol syntax. You can also use just `send`, but also set a list of permitted for output associations (the behaviour is not equivalent, of course):

```
class Category
  has_many :posts
  has_many :images

  has_many :emails
end

def get_all(association)
  self.send(association).size if association.in?([:posts, :images])
end

one_category.get_all(:emails) #=> nil
```